# Unable to add Migration to Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I downloaded a sample Asp.net 5, Mvc 6, EF 7 project from internet. It is working fine, but when I try to add Migrations using console it says

Please run "**Dnu restore**" to generate a new lock file.

I ran this inside the **src/projectName** folder on console, If I try to run
**dnx ef** command its still says the same error.

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: Did you check if all your dependencys have the same version?

Comment: Posting your project.json would help troubleshoot.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I have not idea how to post project.json :( could you please help me with this.